# You are publicly sharing your App Secret. Do not expose the App Secret in browsers: error while calling getStream API from Angular

Tags: angular, api, angular6, getstream-io

I am using GetStream API to get feed data. When I am calling API its gives me an error that You are publicly sharing your App Secret. If I pass it null then it gives me 403 error with message "Missing token, in client side mode please provide a feed secret"

```
import * as stream from 'getstream';
export class StreamClientService {
client: stream.Client;
constructor() {
this.client = stream.connect(APP_TOKEN,APP_KEY, APP_ID);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you interact with a feed client-side:

```
client = stream.connect('YOUR_API_KEY');
user1 = client.feed('user', '1', token);
```

Server-side you need to create the token for that feed and pass it to the client:

```
client = stream.connect('YOUR_API_KEY', 'API_KEY_SECRET');
user1 = client.feed('user', '1');
token = user1.token;
```

Comment: What do you mean by client side and server side here?

Comment: And from where i will get token here: user1 = client.feed('user', '1', token);

Comment: server-side token is an attribute of the feed object (last line from the second code snippet)